# Firebase: Get timestamp of last user token refresh?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to get the timestamp of when the user's token was last refreshed so that if it hasn't been updated for a while, I can force a refresh to make sure I have up-to-date user data (e.g. custom claims, if the token was revoked) and also to use as an approximate current time instead of relying on the user's clock.

Is there a way to get this timestamp?

I'm aware there's an "expiry" for the refresh token and the refresh token is updated every hour but I'm cautious the "every hour" value could change.

Comment: Are you running this check from the client side or from your server? If you are running it from the client side, you can look at the `iat` field in the ID token. This is the time of the last refresh.

Comment: @bojeil On the client. Thanks, I came up with doing firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult(true) (to force a refresh) and then grabbing the "issuedAtTime" of the token. This appears to get the server time to within a few seconds even if I change the client clock. Is this solution unlikely to break and isn't taking advantage of implementation details? I've seen a few posts on getting an accurate client-side timestamp when using Firebase so I'm surprised this solution hasn't been posted before.

Comment: can you explain your flow more? You get the issued at timestamp and send it to your server. And then what happens?

Comment: My app has paid subscriptions where subscription records are stored in Firestore. I want a basic check that a subscription hasn't expired yet. To check for valid subscriptions, the client asks Firestore for subscriptions for the current user (you can have multiple subscriptions) that have an expiry date greater than the current time. I don't want to rely on the client's clock. The "issuedAtTime" seems ideal for this i.e. I would refresh the token, get the time, then query Firestore. I'm aware this kind of thing can get easily hacked by the way but so can most IAP payment schemes.

Comment: Why don't you just save the expiration time of the subscription in your Firestore database (assuming you do that from a server environment and have this write protected)? and then just check the user is authenticated and the current time is less than the expiration time in your Firestore rule? That is the secure way to do it.

Comment: @bojeil  I do store the expiration time in Firestore. However, to perform the client side query that the subscription has not expired, it seems the client has to pass in the current time in the query. If I rely on the client's "new Date()", the user could change their system clock back in time to keep using expired subscriptions. Refreshing the user token on the client then using issuedAtTime as the current time (it only needs to have day accuracy) seems to fix this well enough. Does that make sense or am I making this overly complex?

Comment: The logic has to be run server side or via security rules. Just use the [`request.time`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) and compare it to the user's subscription time. Something like if the request does not exceed expiration and the user is authenticated, process request.

Comment: @bojeil Why server side? Using the security rules to enforce the time/expiry is problematic because if a user has multiple subscriptions they'd be unable to list them all if needed because you'd get a security error for the whole query if one has expired. I'm not seeing how this improves on the client side check using the issuedAtTime as the current time.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are doing. Client side processing is insecure and passing a plain iat is as bad as passing a `new Date()`.

Comment: @bojeil It's essentially a license check for if you're allowed to use a paid desktop app that has no online component. Any "if the server says you've paid for a subscription then unlock the paid features of the app" logic is going to be insecure. Even if the client calls a cloud function to do the check, a determined hacker could just strip out the check. Passing the iat at least prevents honest users from being locked out if their clock time is set wrong. Does that make more sense?

Comment: When you call a server, you would pass the ID token to verify the user identity. The ID token guarantees integrity and you can trust only its encoded payload. The subscription is served from a server. You do the check at that level. Any client side check is superficial and only useful from a UI perspective. The enforcement has to be done server side.

Comment: @bojeil For a desktop app with no server side component, there ultimately has to be code along the lines of "if (verifyUserHasPaid()) userHasPaid = true". Even if the verifyUserHasPaid() function consists of a secure server call, a hacker can just edit it out or add some code to flip the userHasPaid flag. Yes, the actual check is more reliable on a server but I don't see how it helps that much when the client code ultimately determines what is done with what the server says back. You say "UI perspective" but most successful paid desktop can be easily hacked like this and they make money.