# How to get firebase last auth token Refresh time

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to get when did the token refreshed last time from firebase. How can I get that?

I have refered answer based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615811/firebase-get-timestamp-of-last-user-token-refresh) post.
But did not understand properly please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Javascript SDK you can use `getIdTokenResult` method and check for `issuedAtTime`. It is defined as "The ID token issued at time formatted as a UTC string." in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.IDTokenResult#issuedattime).

```js
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser

if (user) {
  user.getIdTokenResult().then((result) => {
    const {issuedAtTime, expirationTime} = result 
    console.log(`This token was issued at: ${issuedAtTime}`)
    console.log(`This token will expire at: ${expirationTime}`)
  })
}
```